# Is there anyway to encrypt oracle stored procedures?( Oracle 11g)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I don't want clients see my stored procedures,Is there anyway to encrypt oracle stored procedures??

Comment: sure. but then the question becomes, "how do I keep my clients from decrypting my stored procedures"? At some point, the procedures HAVE to get executed, and that means they get decrypted. You're chasing your own tail and trying to eat it... at some point you're down to just a mouth.

Comment: so you say ,encrypting,is not good idea?

Answer (score 6):

You can "wrap" a pl/sql package body.  It is obfuscated - see [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/wrap.htm)

Comment: It works well, but be aware it takes only a few minutes on Google to get the "de-obfuscator"