# What does the `text` column of the `all_source` table contain when a procedure does not reveal its source?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to read source codes of user functions and procedures in an Oracle database. I came through one record that returns a strange string of characters in the `text` field of the `all_source` table, while the field should contain the source of a given subprogram.

My question is what does this string represent. Is it the result that is returned when the source of a given subprogram is not made available? That is, when it is for example encrypted? Moreover, is it possible for a `text` field to be `null`?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20888234/1847592).  De-obfuscator is available only for old Oracle versions.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff thanks. Though I don't aim at "cracking" the subprogram's code, rather I am interested more in comparisons between databases to be sure a subprogram with a given name is the same one in the other database. Therefore if a subprogram is encrypted in a deterministic way, its string will be a good medium for comparisons. I just want to make sure if this is what happens when we obfuscate code in oracle. That an unintelligible string is given, that is independent from the oracle db version, i.e. alway the same one. And if the field can be null and what would that mean.

Comment: Obfuscation methods used in Oracle 9 and 10 are different.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff is there any way then to exclude obfuscated source code from such comparison. can I get the information from the db, without parsing, to know whether I access a proper source code or some unreadable stuff?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff from the link you provided I understand that obfuscated code should make it unavailable in `all_source`. I'm not sure how to understand it. There will be no corresponding record, `text` column will be null or like in my case there will be garbage?

Comment: See [how to detect obfuscated code](http://devcorner.georgievi.net/pages/database/oracle_database/oracle_dba/list-obfuscated-plsql-packages).  Of course `text` will be not null - encrypted data is required to compile a packet/procedure, it must present and must be valid.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff if you could sum these comments up in an answer, I could set the question as solved. nevertheless, you helped me a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: I'm too lazy to write a complete answer :-)  Make it yourself (it is allowed on SO)